# Bluetooth only working with BLUEMAN

Tags: bluetooth

I have just **upgraded to Odin**, and my bluetooth didn't work (stuck in descovering devices), just as the older version had to **install Blueman** again to make it work, is it some kind of bug? or something I have to fix regarding my hardware? any help will be appreciated , thanks!

My bluetooth card is `Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless-AC 9560 [Jefferson Peak]`

Comment: Add your system specs please.

Comment: my [specs](https://paper.dropbox.com/doc/SPECS-eOS-ODIN--BRqBMtNZHD5qMr628Oc3l3g7AQ-zMxCLkB6jKcY7wOH4iyxq) lscpu, is this enough?

Comment: try with `lspci` so that we can know what bluetooth card you have.

Comment: OK, sorry about that, here are my [lspci specs](https://paper.dropbox.com/doc/SPECS-eOS-ODIN--BRqBMtNZHD5qMr628Oc3l3g7AQ-zMxCLkB6jKcY7wOH4iyxq)

Comment: Since your hardware is quite recent I recommend installing HWE kernels. They have more updated drivers. `sudo apt install --install-recommends linux-generic-hwe-20.04`. I can't say for sure this will solve it, but it is worth a try.

Comment: Another possible solutions [1. Disabling fastboot if you dualboot with windows](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi#about_dual-boot_with_windows_and_fast-boot_enabled), 2. Restarting the module with `sudo rmmod btusb && sudo modprobe btusb`

Comment: Thanks Maccer for your answer, don't have dualboot. should I uninstall Blueman before trying these solutions?

Comment: I uninstalled Blueman, installed the new kernel and bluetooth now works smoothly thanks a lot @Maccer for your help.

Comment: Please reboot your system and check if it is still working. Just to be sure everything is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Possible solutions:

**1. HWE kernel with updated drivers:**

Since your hardware is quite recent I recommend installing HWE kernels. They have more updated drivers. `sudo apt install --install-recommends linux-generic-hwe-20.04.

**[2. Disabling fastboot if you dualboot with windows](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi#about_dual-boot_with_windows_and_fast-boot_enabled)**

You need to go to your Windows system and then “Control Panel→Hardware and Sound→Power Options→System Settings”. Select “Chooose what the power buttons do” to access the System Settings from the Power Options. Then disable the “Fast Startup” option in “Shutdown Settings”. This will cause Windows to fully shutdown and may solve the issue.

**3. Restarting the module**

With `sudo rmmod btusb && sudo modprobe btusb`. If after a reboot the bluetooth module stops working again, it is necessary to enable the systemd service.